# How to highlight just the name (not the extension) for renaming?

Tags: nautilus, file-extension

Is there a way to turn it off so that when you're renaming a file, it doesn't highlight the extension?

Answer (score 7):

Use something else than Nautilus' *List View* mode. It works fine in the *Compact View* and *Icon View* modes. Apparently it's a regression: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627110

**Update:**
This is now fixed in the development version of Ubuntu 11.10 (Nautilus 3.0.1.1).

Comment: How annoying. Do you suppose there's a chance of Ubuntu pulling the available patch into maverick-updates?

Answer (score 1):

When I right click a file and select Rename, or press F2, the extension isn't highlighted.

To answer your question: you don't have to do anything.

Comment: I think he wants to make F2 hightlight file WITH extension.

Comment: No, he wants to highlight just the name.

Answer (score 1):

You should try pressing F2 twice and extension will highlight.

Comment: This didn't work but changing to icon view worked!!! Thanks for the tip

Comment: Yep, it only works on icon view. I really do not understand why in list mode it highlights the name plus the extension. It makes no sense.

Answer (score -2):

to get only name without extension:

```
${var%.ext}
```

where ".ext" is extension

following a test script. to effect changes alter the commented line

```
for name in `find ./path -iname "*pattern*.ext" `; do
    new_name=${name%.ext}newextension
    if [ "$new_name" != "$name" ]; then
        echo “$name => $new_name”
        # mv “$name” “$new_name”
    fi
done
```

Comment: find does not belong in a for-loop. Use a "while read"-loop. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29