# Rename selection default was just for the name and now it's even for the extension

Tags: 10.10, nautilus-elementary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to highlight just the name (not the extension) for renaming?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6724/how-to-highlight-just-the-name-not-the-extension-for-renaming)

I remember kind of one year ago that when I was renaming a file the default selection was for the name, while the extension where not selected, this way, suppose you have a `file.doc`, you press F2, type gongigongi and then enter the result was a file named `gongigongi.doc`, while now it's `gongigongi`.

Any way to get that feature back?

Comment: It works fine for me. When I rename it either using F2 or right-click, the extension is preserved. However I recall a couple of occasions when the extension disappeared, it's weird.

Comment: I think this is a bug that was recently fixed in Maverick-proposed. All I know is I have suffered from this not working (recently) but now it works again.

Comment: yes I agree, would you like I delete it or do you think about that? - sorry for overworking you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F2 hightlights only the name when you are not on list view mode. So that, in icon view and compact list, it must work.